# Use of and with negation of the number

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I read this line somewhere and I can't figure out its use

```
private void bitUpdate(int[] bit, int idx, int val) {
        while (idx < bit.length) {
            bit[idx] += val;
            if (bit[idx] >= MOD)
                                bit[idx] -= MOD;
            idx += (idx & -idx);
    }
}
```

`idx` initially is `1`

```
bit[100100]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.......}

val=1

MOD = 1000000007
```

I can't figure out the use of this line

```
idx += (idx & -idx);
```

it adds idx to the and of the number with its negation what do we acheive in and -ing with itself and its negation ?

Comment: I can't see what it's for either. Where did this code come from?

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/15400915

Comment: Source==^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Sorry, but "I can't interpret this awful code" is off-topic here.  You will need to ask the author of this code.

Comment: This is to update a binary indexed tree (Fenwick tree)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`idx & -idx` is "bit twiddling", and is actually used by the Java Runtime Library.

Method [`Integer.lowestOneBit(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#lowestOneBit-int-) is implemented as `return i & -i;`, with a comment saying it's from Section 2-1 of *Hacker's Delight* by Henry S. Warren, Jr. (Addison Wesley, 2002).

The javadoc of the method says:

> Returns an `int` value with at most a single one-bit, in the position of the lowest-order ("rightmost") one-bit in the specified `int` value. Returns zero if the specified value has no one-bits in its two's complement binary representation, that is, if it is equal to zero.

So, if `idx` is initially 1, then `lowestOneBit()` is the unchanged value, and adding that to itself repeatedly is the same as:

```
idx <<= 1;
```

However that is only true if the initial number has exactly one bit set.

If the initial number has multiple bits set, the progression is different, e.g. if `idx` is initially 52428:

```
idx                idx & -idx
                                         1100110011001100 =  52428
1100110011001100 + 0000000000000100 =    1100110011010000 =  52432
1100110011010000 + 0000000000010000 =    1100110011100000 =  52448
1100110011100000 + 0000000000100000 =    1100110100000000 =  52480
1100110100000000 + 0000000100000000 =    1100111000000000 =  52736
1100111000000000 + 0000001000000000 =    1101000000000000 =  53248
1101000000000000 + 0001000000000000 =    1110000000000000 =  57344
1110000000000000 + 0010000000000000 =   10000000000000000 =  65536
    then  <<= 1  from here             100000000000000000 = 131072
                                      1000000000000000000 = 262144
```

To confirm, you can see the above with code like this:

```
int idx = 52428;
while (idx <= 0x40000) {
    String bits1 = Integer.toBinaryString(idx);
    String bits2 = Integer.toBinaryString(idx & -idx);
    idx += (idx & -idx);
    String bits3 = Integer.toBinaryString(idx);
    System.out.printf("%20s + %20s = %20s = %6d%n", bits1, bits2, bits3, idx);
}
```

```
    1100110011001100 +                  100 =     1100110011010000 =  52432
    1100110011010000 +                10000 =     1100110011100000 =  52448
    1100110011100000 +               100000 =     1100110100000000 =  52480
    1100110100000000 +            100000000 =     1100111000000000 =  52736
    1100111000000000 +           1000000000 =     1101000000000000 =  53248
    1101000000000000 +        1000000000000 =     1110000000000000 =  57344
    1110000000000000 +       10000000000000 =    10000000000000000 =  65536
   10000000000000000 +    10000000000000000 =   100000000000000000 = 131072
  100000000000000000 +   100000000000000000 =  1000000000000000000 = 262144
 1000000000000000000 +  1000000000000000000 = 10000000000000000000 = 524288
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us use the value of `idx=1` from the beginning to understand what the expression `(idx & -idx)` does.

8-bit binary representation:
    1  = 00000001, 
    -1 = 11111111

Now, using the `&` operator, `1 & -1` gives `1`.
Therefore, `idx` gets incremented to `2` in `idx+= (idx & -idx);`

```
 2  = 00000010, 
-2 = 11111110
```

and `2` & `-2` gives `2`.
Therefore, `idx` gets incremented to `4`.

```
4  = 00000100, 
-4 = 11111100
```

and `4` & `-4` gives `4`.
Now, `idx` gets incremented to `8`.

As per above, `(idx & -idx) = idx`.